# Very broad question, matches something?

Tags: support, specific-question, asking-questions, site-recommendation

I have a quite broad question that I don't know where I should ask.

I'll try to explain from a very general perspective: I want to put text into some structure (like json) and generate from that something that can be converted into a handful of languages (like html, markdown or latex, I would like not to constrain that yet) so that from those languages something readable can be generated in different formats (pdf, docx, a webpage, a wiki site). The original structure should be readable and play well with github too.

The question is how to structure that information/text so that it fits to be easily converted to other formats, read by humans and checked diffs (branches, etc.) in Github.

It's a usability question that involves not only languages and programming but also technologies, usability and much more. I'm not sure whether stackoverflow is broad enough or I should go somewhere else (or nowhere else).

I tried to summarize the question, I can add more details if needed (sorry if there are too many now). Thank you.

Comment: Well, what's the question? All you have here is an "I want".

Comment: The question is which structure/language/technology fits better the purpose. At this moment I'm thinking about Javascript objects written according to CoffeeScript. But there is a long way from that to LaTeX or Markdown. (PD: added now)

Comment: Try asking your question on http://programmers.stackexchange.com, but make sure it's specific enough to be answerable.  If you're not sure, [ask the duck](http://hwrnmnbsol.livejournal.com/148664.html) first.

Comment: To answer your question:  Use XML

Comment: ... and parse with regexen. Now you've got 42 problems.

Comment: @Matt I thought it was [100](http://xkcd.com/1171/)

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter [That isn`t where that comes from](http://www.jwz.org/). The original was "now they have two problems".

Comment: @Asad actually [Jamie Zawinski](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247#comment-3085) repurposed an older quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question still isn't entirely clear to me, but I think [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) might be the right site for it.

Before you post, I suggest you try to explain your question to someone who hasn't been trying to solve this problem for a while first and see if it's clear enough. If not, maybe add an example or two.

Note that straight up "what language should I use" questions are off-topic pretty much everywhere on Stack Exchange. But, I can see a data format design/choice question being potentially well-received if it's clear and specific enough.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I talk to a [dust mite](http://www.giantmicrobes.com/ca/products/dustmite.html) myself.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I personally have found that beginning to write a question for SO is a very good "ask the duck" exercise.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not sure whether this makes much sense but...

**Context**: I am thinking about using JSON, possibly using the syntax of CoffeeScript, which may be slightly more human readable, so _I can make a guess about a possible answer_ and to some extent a comparison about this answer and other plausible answers.

**Question**: Do you think it may make sense to create it as a wiki post and let better answers or additional considerations emerge through wiki collaboration? Or should I just post the question and hope for something better than my current guess?

Comment: I [tried already](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/193447/format-text-in-a-generic-and-reusable-way) hopefully I didn't do something horrible. Thank you again.

Comment: @Trylks Good luck. :)